# this versus function property in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a static variable in my js. From what I know with my little js knowledge is, I can do it using this two ways.

```
function foo (){

    if (this.counter==undefined){this.counter=1}
    else {this.counter++ } ;

}

function foo (){

    if (foo.counter==undefined){foo.counter=1}
    else {foo.counter++ } ; 

}
```

Are these two things essentially the same or I need to to careful in selecting one versus other.

Another question I have is: why var is not needed when doing these?

Comment: you need to read about **scope**

Comment: I have no clue about the implementation in javascript, but usually a construction like `foo.counter` makes the variable `counter` available from any `foo` object. (e.g. `var a = new Foo(); var b = new Foo(); a.counter === b.counter;`. I am not sure if that is the case with javascript too.

Comment: Are you planning on using `foo` to create objects using `new` or just calling it as a function without the `new`?

Comment: My objective is to call it as a function.

Comment: Okay, and just to clarify, are you planning on calling the function on an object like `something.foo()`, or just on its own like `foo()`?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: Then read [MDN's introduction to the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You will soon realize that this is not what you want.

Comment: @ Bergi: Thanks, I think you are right. @go-oleg: just on its own like foo().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent.  In your first example, you are using `this`.  `this` can actually change depending on how the function is being called.

```
function showThis(){
    console.log(this);
}

var obj = { };
obj.showThis = showThis;

showThis(); // gives 'window', or the top-most scope of your page
obj.showThis(); // gives obj as 'this'
```

If you are always calling the function the same way, then this would just mean the value `counter` is tracked as a property on `window.counter`.  This is bad, because you may accidentally have an actual variable named `counter` in that scope, that you are now using in a different way somewhere else.  If you are not calling it the same way everytime, then `this` will be different and probably not giving you your desired behavior.

If you are trying to keep a count on the number of times `foo` is being called, independent of how/who is calling it, then your second approach is more appropriate.  For the sake of code clarify/convention, I would write it this way:

```
function foo (){
    // If counter does not exist, create it and initialize it to 0.
    foo.counter = foo.counter || 0;
    foo.counter++;
}

foo.counter; // undefined, since foo has never been called yet
foo();
foo.counter; // is now 1
```

Comment: This absolutely clarifies what I wanted to understand. Thanks Matt.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

`var` is used to create a variable in the current scope.

Both the approaches you are taking are setting a property on an object that exists in a wider scope.

Comment: Can you please clarify, what happens if I have var this.counter=1 rather than this.counter=1 in the first case?

Comment: You get an exception. `var` is used to declare variables, not properties on objects.